# Parse HTML Tags with content by Regex in Java

Tags: java, html, html-parsing

I want to parse html tags and tags' content. I can load html as a string with Java `UrlConnection`. I use this regex expression: `<([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*)\\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\\1>` but I cannot get all tags. Is there more flexible regex expression for getting all kind of tags. Note : I can do all these jobs with **Jsoup** easily.
But i should not use any libraries.

```
<div id="footer">   
    <div id="footerbody">
        <div id="footerabout">
            <h3>Bilgi</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/page/history">Tarihçe</a></li>
                <li><a href="/page/visionandmission">Vizyon ve Misyon</a></li>
                <li><a href="/page/education">Eğitim</a></li>
                <li><a href="/page/staff">Kadro</a></li>
                <li><a href="/page/labs">Laboratuvarlar</a></li>
                <li><a href="/page/classrooms">Sınıflar</a></li>
                <li><a href="/page/commissions">Komisyonlar</a></li>
            </ul>
       </div>
       <div id="footersitemap">
        <h3>Site Haritası</h3>
       </div>
</div>
```

is it possible to I get this output.

```
tag : div
   content : id=footer
```

...etc.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 ?

Comment: some questions worth -100

Comment: @noone: Countered by [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1733489/581205). For a quick and dirty solution it's just fine (and for a real parsing it's very bad idea).

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you don't want to use libraries?
You should never use Regex for parsing HTML and other markup languages.
Regex is not made for that purpose.
Use dedicated libraries for doing so.
You can use [HTML Cleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/), [NekoHTML](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/) and [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/).
They are good html parsers.

Comment: But i should not use library.

Comment: ..You should not try to use Regex for a job that requires a parser.

Answer (score 0):

Everybody seems to be so upset by the fact that someone tries to parse HTML with regexes, so that you could wait ages for an answer.

The problem is here

```
<div id="footer">   
    <div id="footerbody">
         <div id="footerabout">
         .... whatever
         </div>
```

Your regex matches the whole text above, from the outermost opening to the innermost closing `div`.

If you knew that you text stays like this, you could fix it somehow. Writing a regex recognizing three nested `div`s might be a nice exercise. But I'd really go for some real parser.